# why is my debug break point not hitting on my lamda function (java)?

Tags: eclipse, java-8

HI I am having a spring boot java application and I am using eclipse. I am using java streams and I am placing a break point on one of my lambda function .
For example in the below code i am putting a break point on the line 
 System.out.println("filter request start date" + filterRequest.getRangeStartDate()); but it didnt hit here. any idea what should i do ?

```
    @Override
    public List<DropdownDTO> findAll(MessageHistoryCampaignFilterRequest filter) {

        List<Campaign> campaigns = campaignRepository.findAll();

        List<Campaign> filteredResults = campaigns.stream()

                .filter(getFilterPredicate(filter))

                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));

        return filteredResults.stream()

                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Campaign::getStartDate))

                .map(campaignMapper::toDropdownDTO)

                .collect(toList()); 
}


    protected Predicate<Campaign> getFilterPredicate(MessageHistoryCampaignFilterRequest filterRequest) {

        Predicate<Campaign> predicate = campaign -> true;

        if(filterRequest.getAccountIds() != null && !filterRequest.getAccountIds().isEmpty()) {

            predicate.and( campaign -> filterRequest.getAccountIds().contains(campaign.getAccount())  );

        }

        if(filterRequest.getCampaignStatuses() != null && !filterRequest.getCampaignStatuses().isEmpty()) {

            predicate.and( campaign -> filterRequest.getCampaignStatuses().contains(campaign.getStatus()) );

        }


        predicate.and( campaign ->

        {

        System.out.println("filter request start date" + filterRequest.getRangeStartDate());

        System.out.println("filter request end date" + filterRequest.getRangeEndDate());

        System.out.println( campaign.getStartDate().isAfter(filterRequest.getRangeStartDate()) && campaign.getStartDate().isBefore(filterRequest.getRangeEndDate()) );

        System.out.println(  campaign.getEndDate().isAfter(filterRequest.getRangeStartDate()) && campaign.getEndDate().isBefore(filterRequest.getRangeEndDate()) );

        return ( campaign.getStartDate().isAfter(filterRequest.getRangeStartDate()) && campaign.getStartDate().isBefore(filterRequest.getRangeEndDate()))  ||

               ( campaign.getEndDate().isAfter(filterRequest.getRangeStartDate())&& campaign.getEndDate().isBefore(filterRequest.getRangeEndDate()));

        }

        );

        return predicate;
    }
```

appreciate any help
thank you

Comment: You are ignoring the result of `predicate.and(…)` but using the original `predicate`. Three times in a row.

Comment: yes that is the correct answer . i can accept your answer if you post it . thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mind the [documentation of `Predicate.and`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-):

> Returns a composed predicate that represents a short-circuiting logical AND of this predicate and another.

Emphasis on *returns*.

So when you call it like `p1.and(p2)`, it is not altering the behavior of `p1` nor `p2` but returning a new predicate that is a composition of the two predicates.

So you have to replace your `predicate.and(…)` calls with `predicate = predicate.and(…)` in your code, to alter the behavior of the subsequent use of `predicate`.